# Intercalar dos listas

Tags: java, array

Tengo dos listas, quiero que en la primera de ellas se almacene la segunda de la siguiente manera:
Array a1:
[10, 20, 30]
Array a2:
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Array resultante:
[10, 4, 20, 5, 30, 6, 7, 8]
El array resultante seria almacenado en el array a1 y para ellor tengo un metodo al que por parametro le paso ambos arrays de tipo Integer.

```java
public static void interleave(List<Integer> a1, List<Integer> a2){
    Integer[] b = new Integer[a1.size() + a2.size()];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        for (; i < a1.size();) {
            if (k % 2 == 0) {
                b[k] = a1.get(i);
                i++;
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (; j < a1.size();) {
            if (k % 2 != 0) {
                b[k] = a2.get(j);
                j++;
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    List<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b));
    a1.clear();
    a1.addAll(b1);
}
```

Despues de ejecutar el programa el array a1 me queda de la siguiente forma:
[10, 4, 20, 5, 30, 6, null, null]
Ahora solo me falta cambiar los valores que estan a null por los numero no puestos que coinciden con el array a2 y son los dos ultimos de este. Y es en esta parte donde estoy atascado.
Hay que mencionar que los arrays que mencione son de ejemplo y que pueden pasar cualquier tipo de arrays Integer con cualquier valor ya sea a1 mas grande que a2 o que tengan el mismo tamño.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que esta trabajando con List no es necesario crear arreglos, se puede hacer uso del método `List.add(index, valor);` que adiciona el `valor` en el indice especificado

```
public static void interleave(List<Integer> a1, List<Integer> a2){
  int index = 1;
  for(Integer valor : a2){
    if(index < a1.size())    
      a1.add(index, valor);
      index = index + 2;
    }else{
      //aca copiar el resto de a2 al final de a1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cual es el valor de un iterador si de todos modos vas a usar un indice?

Answer (score 1):

propongo una posible solución. Que recoge ambas casuísticas a1.size() > a2.size() y viceversa.

Para ello, he decidido utilizar objetos IteratorList y sus métodos de control y modificación.

```
void interleave(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
ListIterator<Integer> it = list1.listIterator();
int i=0;
while(it.hasNext() && i<list2.size()) {
    it.next();
    it.add(list2.get(i++));
}
while(i<list2.size())
    it.add(list2.get(i++));               
}
```

Comment: cual es el valor de un iterador si de todos modos vas a usar un indice?

Answer (score 0):

Como siempre mejor que un iterador es un spliterador, en nuestro caso usaremos el Stream API como ayuda, aunque como veras bien podrias remplazarlo por una estructura de datos sin problema.

La clase [Stream.Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html) esta pensada para ayudarnos a crear facilmente streams, y es al mismo tiempo un [consumidor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) (una interfaz funcional que procesa sin regresar nada).

Es decir, tiene solo una funcion que se encarga de su llenado (es decir solito llama al metodo interno `add`).
y como cumple ese contrato del `Consumer` solamente necesitamos pasarlo al spliterador como parametro en su metodo `tryAdvance` y solito se llamara para procesar el siguiente elemento del spliterador y automaticamente agregandolo a un stream.

como truco adicional el metodo `tryAdvance` nos regresa un valor booleano, con lo que al llamarlo obtenemos false cuando no hay un valor en el spliterador y el consumidor no se llama, con ello solamente usaremos un operador booleano, el or para que secuencialmente elija uno u otro spliterador que son nuestros origenes de datos.

```
public class Interleaver {

    public static <T> Stream<T> interleavePair(Spliterator<T> left, Spliterator<T> right) {

        Stream.Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();

        while (left.tryAdvance(builder) || right.tryAdvance(builder)) {

        }

        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
Interleaver.interleavePair(names.spliterator(), breeds.spliterator()).forEach(System.out::println);
```